# How do I convert an object into an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello can someone help me understand why my object is not converting into an array so that i can map over it and return and `INPUT` component for each element in my new array.

The logic I have written for the conversion starts here `const formElementsArray = [];`

If you need more information please let me know. I have been debugging for a while and don't understand.

Thanks in advance

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Input from "../../components/UI/Input/Input";
import Button from "../../components/UI/Button/Button";
import classes from "./Auth.css";
class Auth extends Component {
  state = {
    controls: {
      email: {
        elementType: "input",
        elementConfig: {
          type: "email",
          placeholder: "Email Address"
        },
        value: "",
        validation: {
          required: true, // must not be empty
          isEmail: true
        },
        valid: false,
        touched: false
      },
      password: {
        elementType: "input",
        elementConfig: {
          type: "password",
          placeholder: "password",
        },
        value: "",
        validation: {
          required: true,
         minLength: 6
        },
        valid: false,
        touched: false
      }
    },
  };

  checkValidity(value, validation) {
    let isValid = true;

    if (validation.required) {
      isValid = value.trim() !== "" && isValid;
    }

    if (validation.minLength) {
      isValid = value.length >= validation.minLength && isValid;
    }

    if (validation.maxLength) {
      isValid = value.length <= validation.maxLength && isValid;
    }

    return isValid;
  }

  inputChangedHandler = (event, controlName) => {
    const updatedControls = {
      ...this.state.controls,
      [controlName]: {
        ...this.state.controls[controlName],
        value: event.target.value,
        valid: this.checkValidity(
          event.target.value,
          this.state.controls[controlName].validation
        ),
        touched: true
      }
    };
    this.setState({ controls: updatedControls });
  };

  render() {
    const formElementsArray = [];

    for (let key in this.state.controls) {
      formElementsArray.push({
        id: key,
        config: this.state.controls[key]
      });

      const form = formElementsArray.map(formElement => {
        console.log(formElementsArray);

        return (
          <Input
            key={formElement.id}
            inputtype={formElement.config.elementType}
            elementType={formElement.config.elementType}
            elementConfig={formElement.config.elementConfig}
            value={formElement.config.value}
            invalid={!formElement.config.valid}
            shouldValidate={formElement.config.validation}
            touched={formElement.config.touched}
            changed={event => this.inputChangedHandler(event, formElement.id)}
          />
        );
      });
      return (
        <div className={classes.Auth}>
          <form>{form}</form>
          <Button btnType="Success">SUBMIT </Button>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}
export default Auth;
```

Comment: Please share some sample data for `this.state.controls`

Comment: Please provide a minimal example for your object and array

Comment: Also, please explain where is the closing `}` bracket for this loop `for (let key in this.state.controls) {`

Comment: hey @palaѕн it's at the top of this file in an object called `state`.. oh maybe that is the issue there is not closing bracket i hope it is that !

Comment: wow @palaѕн this was the reason why it wasn't working. There was no closing braket around the `forloop` you are a lifesaver!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code and it does convert your state to an array. However inside the map you print the array instead of the element:

```
const form = formElementsArray.map(formElement => {
console.log(formElementsArray);
```

Maybe this is confusing you, it should be:

```
console.log(formElement);
```

When I print your formElementsArray, it is definitely an array:

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
  0: {id: "email", config: {…}}
  1: {id: "password", config: {…}}
  length: 2
  __proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: Hi @HermitCrab ar I see now I was console logging the wrong thing.... The last part of your code is what i want however when I `console.log(formElement)` I only see one object in the array which is the object with email in it. How did you get it to return two objects in the array - it doesn't work for me!

Comment: There is missing closing bracket in your for loop, I didn't have this problem because I was just using part of your code